# 4 points are not isomorphic algebraic sets and CRT

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

In my algebraic geometry class, the professor gave as an example that in general, two pairs of 4 points in $\mathbb{A}^1$ are not isomorphic as algebraic sets. He proved it for $\mathbb{C}$, where isomorphisms of algebraic sets are given by mobius transofrmations, and they preserve the cross-ratio. So for example, $V_1=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $V_2=\{1,-1,i,-2i\}$ will not be isomorphic if I am not mistaken, since the cross ratio for the first will be real and for the second not (they do no lie on a line or a circle).

While this explanation is fine to me, I am having problem with understanding how it settles with the fact that algebraic sets are isomorphic if and only if they have isomorphic coordinate ring. Note that $I(V_1)=\langle(x-1)\cdots(x-4)\rangle$ and $I(V_2)=\langle(x-1)(x+1)(x-i)(x+2i)\rangle$ so by CRT both coordinate rings are isomorphic - as rings - to $\mathbb{C}^4$. Also it seems to me that the isomorphism preserves $\mathbb{C}$ (I thought maybe this was the problem, at first sight)

How do we settle this "contradiction"?

Comment: I think you are confusing different notions. There is an invertible morphism $V_1 \rightarrow V_2$. However, there does not exist an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1$ that maps $V_1$ to $V_2$ (these are homographies, and they preserve cross-ratios).

Comment: Oh I see, that's make sense, thank you

Comment: An even weaker statement is that $V_1,V_2$ are linearly equivalent divisors on $\Bbb{P}^1$